# macOS Monterey: Enable idle screen off, but disable idle sleep, when on battery

Tags: macos, battery, sleep-wake, monterey, power-management

On Windows, the idle screen turn off timer and idle sleep timer are two independent settings. On macOS Monteray, it seems there are no separate settings, but just one, and on battery, it seems the computer goes to sleep mode when the screen gets turned off due to inactivity.

Is it possible to keep it running even after the screen got turned off due to inactivity, and the computer is on battery? I have tried setting screen turn off to "Never" and then manually turning off the screen by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Power, but the laptop went to sleep anyway after a while.

Please do answer "It is impossible on macOS", if it is practically impossible (either it is literally impossible, or it would be too difficult to achieve that so it is better to give up). I will also mark that as the answer.

Google Image: Windows and its independent screen/sleep settings:
[image]

Google Image: Monterey settings. The site recommends just disabling screen off itself, to prevent sleep:
[image]